# How do I solve 'invalid property' issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

I added a gradient background to h3 used below code so to add gradient to the text only.

[gradient text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvdQs.jpg)

```css
.locations-head h3 {
  padding: 4rem 0rem;
  background: linear-gradient(#131c27, #663b34);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class = "locations-head">
  <h3> This is a test </h3>
</div>
```

This is working perfectly fine in firefox but in chrome, it seems background-clip: text; is not working. Developer tools also highlighted this snippet and marked it as invalid property.

Comment: Add `-webkit-background-clip: text;`  also.

Answer (score 2):

According to [caniuse.com/?search=background-clip](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-clip), even latest version of chrome needs
`-webkit-` browser prefix for `background-clip` property.

```css
.locations-head h3 {
  padding: 4rem 0rem;
  background: linear-gradient(#131c27, #663b34);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class = "locations-head">
  <h3> This is a test </h3>
</div>
```